# Falha ao abrir arquivo após a instalação da aplicação em C# WPF

Tags: c#, arquivo, instalador

Estou criando um instalador em C# utilizando o `visual studio 2017 installer project` nesse projeto existe um manual de usuário ele fica contido na raiz do projeto, quando eu executo ele tanto na versão Debug ou Release, Any CPU ou x86 ele funciona normal, porém quando gero o instalador da minha aplicação e tento executar ele não carrega esse arquivo de manual.

Utilizo o seguinte comando para recuperar o caminho

```
string CaminhoRelatorio = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.FullName + @"\Modelo Manual Usuario.chm";

CaminhoRelatorio = CaminhoRelatorio.Replace("bin\\","");

System.Windows.Forms.HelpNavigator HelpN = System.Windows.Forms.HelpNavigator.TopicId;

System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(null, CaminhoRelatorio, HelpN, ID);
```

O resultado do caminhorelatorio me retorna = `C:\\Users\\pc01\\Desktop\\Sistema\\Modelo Manual Usuario.chm`

porque ele não consegue encontrar esse caminho quando é gerado o instalador? qual o melhor método que posso fazer para resolver esse problema. fazendo com que ele encontre o caminho

Comment: qual mensagem de erro aparece ? afinal, o caminho (pastas+ arquivo) existem e o sistema não acha ? Se você está pegando "CurrentDirectory" pode ser que o instalador seja iniciado em outro diretório, tipo, faz a extração dos arquivos para uma pasta temporária (appdata) e roda um setup, aí o valor da variavel será diferente

Comment: O arquivo está sendo copiado? Ele chega a existir nessa pasta?